# Proper Method to get Num rows from SQL table

Tags: php

I looked at other solutions provided on the site, but only came across those that were open to SQL injection. How can I count the number of rows that have the same email (`$em`) and save it to a variable? Neither does the code below function nor does it display any error. How can I fix this?

```
if (strtolower(filter_var($em, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))) {
  $em = strtolower(filter_var($em, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)); 
  $e_select = $con->prepare("SELECT email FROM users WHERE email=?");
  $e_select->bind_param('s', $em);
  $e_select->execute();
  $e_select->bind_result($idkwhy);
  $e_select->fetch();
  $num_rows_em = $e_select->num_rows;
  if ($num_rows_em > 0) {
    array_push($error_array, "Email already in use<br>");
  }
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main thing you're looking for on the MySQL side is:

```
"SELECT COUNT(email) FROM users WHERE email=?"
```

That will give you the actual number of rows that have the email you specify. From there, get the result of the only row returned by the query. If it is more than 0, you can push an error to your error array.

The updated code will look something like this:

```
if(strtolower(filter_var($em, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))) {
    $finalCount = null;
    $em = strtolower(filter_var($em, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)); 
    $e_select = $con->prepare("SELECT COUNT(email) FROM users WHERE email=?");
    $e_select->bind_param('s', $em);
    $e_select->execute();
    $e_select->bind_result($count);

    while ($e_select->fetch()) {
        $finalCount = $count;
        break;
    }

    if(intval($finalCount) > 0) {
        array_push($error_array, "Email already in use<br>");
    }
}
```

For more information: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/counting-rows.html

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. However, I tried the COUNT() but the code refused to work properly.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a code sample which should work... Hard to test as I don't have your data but give it a go. :)

Comment: I appreciate your effort! I am getting this error -Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result() in /home4/paul/halpper.com/includes/form_handlers/register_handler.php on line 65. I tried playing around with the code a bit too but it kept showing similar errors. Do I need the bind result parts for getting the number of rows? Can the code be made concise? Thanks a ton.

Comment: My apologies! I got the order wrong and used the incorrect function. Please try again?